# Why is the command line needed to erase CDs and DVDs

Tags: dvd, cd, brasero

Ubuntu 12.10 Newbie questions. Why do you have to use command prompts to erase CDs & DVDs on Ubuntu 12.10 when it has disc burning software like Brasero?  Those commands are not working.

I do not see an option for tools any where on the program.

Comment: Why are there dislike votes? I just want an explanation. That's what askubuntu is all about! People can be so ignorant.....

Comment: The down votes are at least partly because you did not ask the question in the title.  I have edited your question with a better title.  If you accept that, your response may get much more positive.

Comment: Please keep your posts to **one question only** - that's the way a Q&A site works best.

Comment: Generally upvotes do not mean "I kile your question, please someone help him". Upvotes are meant to express that "This question demonstrates research efforts and is likely to help future visitors". Therefore, the negative score of your question is not because of people here being ignorant.

Answer (score 2):

Brasero is able to erase RW CD/DVD.

Goto Tools > Blank

[image]

Comment: "Brasero is able to erase RW CD/DVD.

Goto Tools > Blank"  Where is the tools option?

Comment: Move your pointer to the top menu bar where it says 'Brasero Disc Burner' and the menu options will appear. Alternatively see here http://askubuntu.com/a/131647/32548 on using HUD

Comment: I'm completely lost. No options appear & I don't know how to make the HUD work either. I guess I'll just keep experimenting & see what happens. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Never mind, I found how to open HUD on here. I juust had to tap the alt key. Thank you for the help! :)