# How can I restore session in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

When I start Ubuntu's version of Firefox, there is no button restore previous session, just some Ubuntu buttons. How can I restore the session in Ubuntu's version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move your mouse cursor to the top panel. When hovering the panel a menu will appear, click on history and then choose "Restore previous session".

Alternatively you can use the Ubuntu HUD function.

[To use HUD](https://askubuntu.com/q/131617/58950), you need to have a Firefox window selected, then press the ALT key and type "SESSION". Again choose "Restore previous session".

That should be that.

Answer (score 3):

Simply change your home page to default `Mozilla Firefox Start Page`.

Open Firefox, type `about:home` in your address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this will open the default Firefox start page.

[image]

To set this as your home page, open Firefox preferences by going to `Edit` ➤ `Preferences`.

Under `General` tab, below `Startup`, click on `Use Current Page`.

[image]

For more control over Firefox sessions use [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) addon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Firefox to always open your previous tabs and windows:

1. Navigate to `Edit > Preferences`
2. In the `General` tab, under **Startup**, you will be able to change "When Firefox starts"
3. Select "Show my tabs and windows from last time" in the dropdown menu.

[image]